# echo array as column mysqli?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am working on a recipe site for a school project, and I am trying to echo out two columns of arrays from my database in mysqli.

The arrays look like this:
[image: Arrays for recipedatabase]

And when I echo them out I would like them too look like this:
[image: Column echo arrays]

I have literally tried everywhere to find and answer.

My database name is "opskriftreg", and the connection to it works, the rest of the code comes out.

Comment: this is a poorly structured db, normalisation would help a lot

Comment: Don't have all the columns on there, just took a sreenshot of the array part

Comment: ideally you never have a comma separated list like that in a db field, you should have another table with recipe_id, ingredient, amount.

Comment: Ah okay. Pretty new to this, so thanks for info :-) Still learning

Comment: you could even have an ingredient(id, ingredient) table then another table with recipe_id, ingredient_id, amount.

Comment: You should look into [normalizing your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Putting comma separated lists into a record usually means that you have yet to learn how [*relational* databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) really work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) to make an array of it,

Example:

```
$data = "hi,hello,helooo";
$my_array = explode($data);
foreach($my_array AS $value)
{
    echo $value."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to complicate things?! simply get the two columns using a normal MySQL query, and do the job through your language:

- select column1, column2 from table;
- get the result in a variable of your used language, $array_of_values for example.
- for every field in the array explode the value by the delimiter ','.
- draw your new table using a loop that goes through the new arrays and write the values in HTML.

For example in PHP:

```
$array_of_values = array('ing1, ing2, ing3', 'amount1, amount2, amount3');
$ings = explode(',',$array_of_values[0]);
$amounts = explode(',',$array_of_values[1]);
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0; $i < count($ings); $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$ings[$i]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$amounts[$i]."</td>";
    echo "<tr/>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: gets an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ']' in // on line 4` Array values line

Comment: You shouldn't copy paste the code as is by the way! you should have just got the Idea because I didn't test the syntax!

Comment: Anyway, Just replace the first line with the following:
$array_of_values = array('ing1, ing2, ing3', 'amount1, amount2, amount3');