# array as column, shows nothing

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Yesterday I asked a question about array, with commas, output as column.
[Check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848578/echo-array-as-column-mysqli)
Today I have come this far:

```
<?php require_once("dbconnection.php"); ?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT amount, ingredients FROM opskriftreg LIMIT 1;";

$ingredients =  explode(',', $row['ingredients']);
$amount      =  explode(',', $row['amount']);

echo '<table>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($ingredients); $i++) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>', $ingredients[i], '</td>';
          echo '<td>', $amount[i], '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';

?>
```

The site shows an empty table now, but no errors, no nothing.

Anybody got any ideas??

Comment: You've got perfect answer there already, **You should look into normalizing your data. Putting comma separated lists into a record usually means that you have yet to learn how relational databases really work.**

Comment: The database connection works. Tried with a different setup, but only showed at array in a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't executed the query..

```
$sql = "SELECT amount, ingredients FROM opskriftreg LIMIT 1;";

// $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_link, $sql);
// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    

$ingredients =  explode(',', $row['ingredients']);
$amount      =  explode(',', $row['amount']);
```

Go to [**mysqli_query**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) for more help.

Comment: Tried this just get two errors. `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters`
`Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

Comment: Fixed it now, but now I am back to square one. Doesn't show anything